# HDFS IO error org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4 i

Tags: hadoop, flume, hadoop2, flume-ng

I am using Flume 1.6.0 in a virtual machine and Hadoop 2.7.1 in another virtual machine .
When I send Avro Events to the Flume 1.6.0 and it try to write on Hadoop 2.7.1 HDFS System. The follwing exception occurs

```
 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:455)] HDFS IO error
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:243)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:235)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:679)
    at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:676)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Thread
```

I try by adding these **.jars** in flume **lib** folder 
=>

**hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar**

**avro-1.7.7.jar**  instead of **avro-1.7.4.jar**

**avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar** instead of  **avro-ipc-1.7.4.jar**

**guava-18.0.jar** instead of **guava-11.0.2.jar**

But the problem is still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

**FlumeNG HDFS Sink** depends on the following **.jar** files

```
hadoop-auth-2.4.0 jar
hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.4.0.jar 
commons-configuration-1.10.jar
```

which are not included in **Flume** **lib** folder .

By adding these **.jars** , the exception has been successfully overcome.