# Facing org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4 while writting to hdfs using flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, emr

I'm trying to write log files to `hdfs` which is in `EMR` using [flume](/questions/tagged/flume) but I'm facing an error.

I have `flume`(`1.6.0` version) on machine X and another `flume` running on machine Y which have `AWS` and I want to populate my log files (to `HDFS` which in `AWS`(`EMR`)) from machine X to machine Y while running agent encounters error in machine Y.

My machine X config:

```
agent.sources = localsource
agent.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks = avro_Sink
agent.sources.localsource.type = spooldir
agent.sources.localsource.spoolDir = /home/dwh/teja/Flumedata/
agent.sources.localsource.fileHeader = true
agent.sources.localsource.channels = memoryChannel
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.channel = memoryChannel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 10000
agent.channels.memoryChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.type = avro
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.hostname= ec2-serverid.compute-1.amazonaws.com
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.port= 8021
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.avro.batchSize = 100
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.avro.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.avro.rollSize = 73060835
agent.sinks.avro_Sink.avro.rollInterval = 0
agent.sources.localsource.interceptors = search-replace regex-filter1
agent.sources.localsource.interceptors.search-replace.type = search_replace
agent.sources.localsource.interceptors.search-replace.searchPattern = ###|##
agent.sources.localsource.interceptors.search-replace.replaceString = | my machineY config:
tier1.sources  = source1
tier1.channels = channel1
tier1.sinks    = sink1
tier1.sources.source1.type = avro
tier1.sources.source1.bind=serverid
tier1.sources.source1.port = 8021
tier1.sources.source1.channels = channel1
tier1.channels.channel1.type= memory
tier1.sinks.sink1.type     = hdfs
tier1.sinks.sink1.channel    = channel1
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://serverid:8020/user/hadoop/flumelogs/
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = Flumedata
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.writeFormat= Text
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.batchSize = 10000
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 73060835
tier1.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
tier1.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
tier1.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

ERROR log:

```
2016-06-08 15:19:01,635 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.process(HDFSEventSink.java:455)] HDFS IO error
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:243)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:235)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:679)
    at org.apache.flume.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.execute(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:676)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If anyone is familiar with this please help.

Comment: Hi Teja, welcome to SO. Are you using your own code and get this error? If it's the case, then you must post the relevant parts. Otherwise, detail the steps that led you to this error.

Comment: Hi Chomel, As You asked i posted my config files.

Comment: This is usually an Hadoop version mismatch. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453336/exception-in-thread-main-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-remoteexception-server-ipc-ver or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634985/error-when-trying-to-write-to-hdfs-server-ipc-version-9-cannot-communicate-with.

Comment: Hi Binary Nerd , Thanks alot for your reply, I saw above link previously but not got clarity with that where this POM file locates and as explained which versions are mis matching.

Comment: Hi Binary Nerd as you said i changed pom file but still facing same issue

Comment: Teja, for Binary Nerd to get notified, you need to prefix its name with `@`: @Binary Nerd

Comment: Does this one help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173503/hdfs-io-error-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-remoteexception-server-ipc-version-9-cannot (seems to match your situation pretty well)

Comment: Of course i tried that too, in that link as he mentioned i add all that jars  by getting same error :@Binary Nerd